# How to do a merge operation in git that fails if it would change the tree hash

Tags: git, merge

I would like to know if there is an way, not involving hooks, to specify some option or strategy to `git merge` that would make the command fail if the merge operation would change the tree hash.

I just want the merge to update the set of commit objects in the branch history.

So, the tree of the commit being merged do not need to be identical to the one in my branch, but the commits in there should not bring changes into the tree of my branch.

Edit:

The `-X ours` strategy is not good enough for what I want, since that strategy can bring changes (as far as there do not conflict with changes in the branch) to the tree.

The `-s ours` neither, since it will silently succeed, leaving me unaware that there are changes in the tree that were never taken care of.

Example:

```
git init
echo foo>foo
git add foo
git commit -m foo
git branch the_branch
echo bar>foo
git commit -a -m bar
echo foo>foo
git commit -a -m foo_again

git checkout master
git merge the_branch --> the tree id remains the same, but the commits are now in master.  Everything is fine

#Example 2
git init
echo foo>foo
git add foo
git commit -m foo
git branch the_branch
echo bar>bar
git commit -a -m bar

git checkout master
git merge the_branch --> the tree id changes; I want it to fail;
```

And this example where trees are different so 'git diff' approach does not work:

```
git init
echo initial>foo
git add foo
git commit -m initial
git branch the_branch
echo foo>foo
git add foo
git commit -m foo
git checkout the_branch
echo bar>foo
git commit -a -m bar
git checkout master
echo bar>bar
git add bar
git commit -m bar
git merge -X ours the_branch
git checkout the_branch
git commit --allow-empty -m empty
git checkout master
git merge the_branch #--> the tree id remains the same (but different than the_branch), the commits are now in master.  Everything is fine
```

Comment: So to clarify: You want the merge to fail if the trees aren't 100% identical?

Comment: @musiKk, See edit.  I want the merge to fail if resulting tree is not identical to the origin tree, but the tree of the commit/s being merged may be different (there could be empty commits, commits already merged into my branch but with conflicts already solved, etc).

Comment: Both commits will point to the same tree then. Git is pretty smart about that. In fact I'm positive that it is impossible to have two identical trees with different hashes.

Comment: Can you draw an ascii diagram showing the expected and actual result? If you want to do a fake merge (i.e. record parents of commit but not change content), there's the `ours` merge strategy.

Comment: @knittl I thought about `ours` as well but I don't think OP wants to throw away changes from the branch but guarantee that there aren't any to begin with. I think a lot of confusion stems from the terms *commit* and *tree*.

Comment: Wrt. your edit: the `ours` strategy does not change anything. The resulting commit will have the exact same tree as its first parent. Don't confuse the `ours` strategy with the `ours` merge option to the `recursive` merge strategy (i.e there's a big difference between `-s ours` and `-X ours`)

Comment: @knittl I'm aware of the differences and what the merge strategies do. I don't seem to fully grok what OP wants. The second comment talks about failing merges then it's about discarding commits... perhaps an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=xy+problem)

Comment: @musiKk, I do not want to discard commits.  I want to bring commits into the branch, but I want to fail if any of those commits bring changes to the tree.

Comment: @musiKk: The comment about differences was meant for the poster :) @juanleon: A merge only brings changes to the tree if the trees are different. So `git diff current_branch to_merge` will show you if the merge will introduce changes.

Comment: @juanleon: Can you please edit your question and include a number of git commands to create a repository (i.e. minimal working example) to fully explain what you want to do and when it should fail/succeed? Right now it's really unclear what your problem exactly is that you are trying to solve.

Comment: @juanleon: from your example script, you can check before merging with `git diff -q master the_branch && echo 'no changes!' && git merge the_branch`. Try it! At least for your sample this will work (please provide a counter-example where it does not work, if there is one)

Comment: @knittl, Example added

Comment: @juanleon: in your example the git diff approach will still work, because both trees are identical (both contain a single file `foo` with content `bar`). The trees are only different after committing the changed file in your branch, but become identical again after doing the same change in your master. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @knittl, you are right; there was a bug in my example that I corrected

Comment: I need to test this more thoroughly, but empty output from `git merge-tree $(git merge-base HEAD branch) HEAD branch` seems to indicate identical trees. This will not pollute the index or working copy.

Comment: Or maybe even a simple `git diff HEAD...branch` (i.e. what changed in branch since it diverged from the current commit (should generally use the same merge base as `merge` would, but safest sure is to perform the merge, check if there are changes and reset --hard if there are, otherwise commit))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have any local changes the following might help:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-commit branch # merge changes from branch into working copy
git diff -q && git commit -m 'no differences' # only commit if there are no changes (i.e. the trees are the same)
git reset --hard # if there were changes, then discard all of them. If changes were already committed, this command is a no-op.
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I would have done, too. However, this is not in a single merge command. But I'm afraid that solution doesn't exist.

Comment: You can always create an alias …

Comment: Note that `git diff -q HEAD branch && git merge branch` will probably suffice for most cases (but might not actually recognize all merges that would result in identical trees)